# How to generate a log file which includes the results of the samplers that are executed in the JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to generate a log file which includes the results of the samplers that are executed in the JMeter script. One thing to clear I don't want the file which is present in the bin folder. I am looking to create a new log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is going for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) plugin

1. Install Flexible File Writer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   [image]
2. Add Flexible File Writer to your Test Plan according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
3. Configure it as follows:

   - Filename: desired location of the output file
   - Write File Header - if you want you can specify header labels here, below example assumes 2 columns: Sampler Name and Status

     ```
     Name,Successful
     ```
   - Record each sample as: here you can specify metrics you want to store, for sampler name and status it will be sufficient to use the following pattern:

     ```
     |sampleLabel|,|isSuccsessful|\r\n
     ```

     [image]
4. Run your JMeter test. Once it's completed you should see a new file containing the metrics of your choice:

   [image]

Comment: This works fine when i execute the script in JMeter but when the script is executed using maven project it shows an exception Please refer link for image of exception: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms99Q.png

Comment: You need to add Flexible File Writer to your project classpath as per [Adding jar's to the /lib/ext directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory), you need to add the next line: `<artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-ffw:2.0</artifact>`. Check out [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/) article for more details. `